# Ignore flag case

Tags: go

Is there anyway to ignore case (case insensitive) of Go flags?

I'd like to make my program forgiving and user friendly as possible.

```
 dbType := flags.String( "dbType", "", "The `dbType` to deploy. )
```

I'd like this flag's value to be initialized if the user enters any of the following:

```
 -dbtype
 -dbType
 -DBTYPE
```

Unfortunately, for this project I am limited to using the `flag` library.

Comment: The standard library `flag` package is case-sensitive.

Comment: @Adrian: And since that's the case (I seriously didn't intend that as a pun), I presume that most Go programs have case-sensitive flag names, as do most programs that are intended for use under Unix-like systems. I'd question the user-friendliness of violating that convention. (I wonder about the convention for Windows programs, but I'm not curious enough to do any research.)

Comment: Typical classical windows command line is case-insensitive, but customarily uppercase. Flags are single-character and denoted by forward slashes rather than dashes. Modern powershell scripts use more unix-like flags, but are still case-insensitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go flags are case-sensitive, so you can't do what you want by default.
But you can set the values you allow the user enter, and let them point to the same variable, ie:

```
const dbTypeUsage = "The `dbType` to deploy."

var dbType string
flag.StringVar(&dbType, "dbType", "", dbTypeUsage)
flag.StringVar(&dbType, "DBTYPE", "", dbTypeUsage)
flag.StringVar(&dbType, "DBType", "", dbTypeUsage)
flag.StringVar(&dbType, "dbtype", "", dbTypeUsage)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your flag in lower case

```
dbType := flags.String( "dbtype", "", "The `dbType` to deploy. )
```

and then just make your flag strings.ToLower() (assuming that your flag is the second argument):

```
args[1] = strings.ToLower(args[1])
err := flagSet.Parse(args[1:])
```